# How to use the SUM function with Group BY in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a SQL statement that returns some records depending on some given variables.

**Query:**

```
SELECT
     country
    ,(MAX(d_views) - MIN(d_views)) AS viewz 
FROM mv_data
WHERE add_date BETWEEN '2022-01-22' AND '2022-01-22' 
GROUP BY title
ORDER BY viewz DESC;
```

**Output:**

| country | viewz |
| --- | --- |
| NG | 14735 |
| NG | 12494 |
| GH | 6099 |
| GH | 5181 |
| GH | 3381 |
| NG | 3293 |
| GH | 2288 |
| NG | 169 |

**What I'm looking for is:**
To use the SUM() function to sum up all the `viewz` according to their country, something like:

| country | viewz |
| --- | --- |
| NG | 30691 |
| GH | 16949 |

**And this is what I did:**

```
SELECT
     country
    ,SUM(MAX(d_views) - MIN(d_views)) AS viewz 
FROM mv_data
WHERE add_date BETWEEN '2022-01-26' AND '2022-01-26'
GROUP BY title
ORDER BY viewz DESC;
```

**But I'm getting this error:**

> #1111 - Invalid use of group function

I also tried to `GROUP BY country` **without** the `SUM()` function and the result is incorrect:

**Query:**

```
SELECT
     country
    ,(MAX(d_views) - MIN(d_views)) AS viewz 
FROM mv_data
WHERE add_date BETWEEN '2022-01-26' AND '2022-01-26'
GROUP BY country
ORDER BY viewz DESC;
```

**Output:**

| country | viewz |
| --- | --- |
| NG | 4918377 |
| GH | 8185474 |

**What I am doing wrong?**

NB: `d_views` is a field in my table. Depending on a given date, we have a minimum value and a maximum value.

Comment: *`SELECT country, ... GROUP BY title ...`* ??? really? If definite `country` value matches one and only one `title` value and backward then use `GROUP BY country`. If not then your query is obviously wrong and produces the output which makes no sense. Study `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` SQL Mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the first as subquery for the second like

```
SELECT
   country
   SUM(viewz) as viewz
FROM (SELECT
     country
    ,MAX(d_views) - MIN(d_views) AS viewz 
FROM mv_data
WHERE add_date BETWEEN '2022-01-26' AND '2022-01-26'
GROUP BY title) t1
GROUP BY country
ORDER BY viewz DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking to use the SUM() function to sum-up all the viewz according to their country just use the following;

```
SELECT
     country
    ,SUM(d_view) AS viewz 
FROM mv_data
WHERE add_date BETWEEN '2022-01-26' AND '2022-01-26'
GROUP BY country
ORDER BY viewz DESC;
```